# Regular Expression syntax in Python with the either or operator

Tags: python

I am trying to find amino acid sequences that start with either L or A and then end in either L or A with two amino acids in between each instance of L or A.

This is what I have:

`re.findall("A|L.{2}A|L", string1)`

output:

`['A', 'L', 'A', 'L', 'A', 'A', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'LNLA', 'A', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'A', 'L', 'A', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'LACA', 'A', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'L', 'LPYA', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'L', 'L', 'A', 'A', 'A']`

I assume the extra L's and A's have something to do with the syntax, but I'm not sure what this | is exactly doing.

Comment: It would help the question a lot if you provided sample input, with the desired output.  Without seeing your input, I agree with @kay3 that it sounds like you want `[AL].{2}[AL]`.

Answer (score 0):

| means "or". So "A|L" means to match a char "A" or "L".

So "A|L.{2}A|L" means to match "A" or "L.{2}A" or "L".

Perhaps what you want is: "[AL].{2}[AL]"

where [ ] is a set of characters, re will match any char in the [ ]. For example "[AaLy]" will match 'A' or 'a' or 'L' or 'y'.

```
import re
string1="AALLLNLALPYAL"
out0=re.findall("[A|L].{2}[A|L]", string1)
print(out0)
```

Output

```
['AALL', 'LNLA', 'LPYA']
```

However, "(A|L).{2}(A|L)" means search by first group in first parenthesis which is A or L, then after arbitrary 2 characters, search the 2nd group by 2nd parenthesis which is A or L. So the output would look different:

```
out1=re.findall("(A|L).{2}(A|L)", string1)
print(out1)
```

Output

```
[('A', 'L'), ('L', 'A'), ('L', 'A')]
```

Well this may not be what you want, right?